# Haskell: Function multiplying elements of list using high order functions

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell so I'm trying to understand high order functions and how they work using map, filter, foldr, foldl, foldr1, foldl1, and operator.

First I wanted to start with a function that multiplies elements in a list and multiplying an empty list returns 1.

I have this so far, but I'm not sure where to go next.

```
mult :: [Int] -> Int
```

Answer (score 4):

Start with **explicit recursion** first... that means do not use foldl/foldr and friends.

Let's start by handling the corner case of an empty list:

```
mult [] = 1
```

Now, we can do something to the first element of a list by doing:

```
mult (x:xs) = x * 3
```

`x` is the first element of the list, while `xs` is the remaining list. So this just multiplies the **first** element of your list with 3.
Now you have to figure out what to replace `3` with in order to make the whole thing do what you want. The rest is already correct, as in:

```
mult :: [Int] -> Int
mult [] = 1
mult (x:xs) = x * <this part is missing, recursion maybe?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should handle the case of an empty list:

```
mult [] = ?
```

Then, what are you trying to do? You want to basically take a list:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

And insert multiplication symbols in between:

```
1 * 2 * 3 * 4
```

I would recommend you look into [how fold works](https://wiki.haskell.org/Fold).

Comment: Basically I just want to multiply a list of 3 numbers, so how would that code end up looking?

Comment: @Mochilla: Ok. So what do you put for the `?`?

Comment: Below I have a test which does this '  te "mult" 5 (multiply [1, 2, 3])
'

Comment: @Mochilla: I mean fill in the blank. What should `?` be?

Comment: Should it be 1? Then I can do `mult xs = foldl (*) xs`?

Comment: @Mochilla: Yes, it should be 1. There is one parameter you are missing for `foldl`, (also I wouldn't name it `xs`... but that isn't the main point here).